# Parsing a T-SQL query using ANTLR4

Tags: t-sql, parsing, antlr4

I'm currently developing a T-SQL parser that will be able to map the query in a database for my school project. So far I've managed to parse most of it but I have a problem that I can't seem to solve.. I'm using C# with [tsql.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/tsql) grammar and ANTLR4.

How do I access the expression? I want to know that I'm in the *select* and that I have some sort of expression, but what kind of expression is the expression? Is it possible to extract only the column name, schema(if there is one) and database(if there is one) from the select_statement?

Whenever I try to access **expression** from the c# code:

context: `GrammarSQLParser.Dml_clauseContext context`
    context.select_statement().query_expression().query_specification().select_list().select_list_elem().expression()

I only get the method CopyFrom(), I don't have any full_column_name() method to access further table_name() and so on..

**edit1:** after close inspection, the expression is a column_ref_expression, but how do I access it from expression? They're different objects..

This is the query:

```
select p.BusinessEntityID,p.FirstName,p.LastName,adresstbl.* from person.Person as p 
join (select bea.BusinessEntityID, adr.AddressLine1, adr.AddressLine2, adr.City, adr.PostalCode from person.BusinessEntityAddress as bea 
join person.Address as adr
on bea.AddressID = adr.AddressID )
as adresstbl 
on not p.BusinessEntityID != adresstbl.BusinessEntityID order by p.BusinessEntityID
```

This is my parse tree:

> Lisp Parse Tree: (tsql_file (batch (sql_clauses (sql_clause
>   (dml_clause (select_statement (query_expression (query_specification
>   select (select_list (select_list_elem (**expression** (full_column_name
>   (table_name (id (simple_id p))) . (id (simple_id BusinessEntityID)))))
>   , (select_list_elem (**expression** (full_column_name (table_name (id
>   (simple_id p))) . (id (simple_id FirstName))))) , (select_list_elem
>   (**expression** (full_column_name (table_name (id (simple_id p))) . (id
>   (simple_id LastName))))) , ***(select_list_elem (table_name (id
>   (simple_id adresstbl)*)) . *)**) from (table_sources (table_source
>   (table_source_item_joined (table_source_item (table_name_with_hint
>   (table_name (id (simple_id person)) . (id (simple_id Person))))
>   (as_table_alias as (table_alias (id (simple_id p))))) (join_part join
>   (table_source (table_source_item_joined (table_source_item
>   (derived_table (subquery (select_statement (query_expression (
>   (query_expression (query_specification select (select_list
>   (select_list_elem (expression (full_column_name (table_name (id
>   (simple_id bea))) . (id (simple_id BusinessEntityID))))) ,
>   (select_list_elem (expression (full_column_name (table_name (id
>   (simple_id adr))) . (id (simple_id AddressLine1))))) ,
>   (select_list_elem (expression (full_column_name (table_name (id
>   (simple_id adr))) . (id (simple_id AddressLine2))))) ,
>   (select_list_elem (expression (full_column_name (table_name (id
>   (simple_id adr))) . (id (simple_id City))))) , (select_list_elem
>   (expression (full_column_name (table_name (id (simple_id adr))) . (id
>   (simple_id PostalCode)))))) from (table_sources (table_source
>   (table_source_item_joined (table_source_item (table_name_with_hint
>   (table_name (id (simple_id person)) . (id (simple_id
>   BusinessEntityAddress)))) (as_table_alias as (table_alias (id
>   (simple_id bea))))) (join_part join (table_source
>   (table_source_item_joined (table_source_item (table_name_with_hint
>   (table_name (id (simple_id person)) . (id (simple_id Address))))
>   (as_table_alias as (table_alias (id (simple_id adr))))))) on
>   (search_condition (search_condition_and (search_condition_not
>   (predicate (expression (full_column_name (table_name (id (simple_id
>   bea))) . (id (simple_id AddressID)))) (comparison_operator =)
>   (expression (full_column_name (table_name (id (simple_id adr))) . (id
>   (simple_id AddressID)))))))))))))) ))))) (as_table_alias as
>   (table_alias (id (simple_id adresstbl))))))) on (search_condition
>   (search_condition_and (search_condition_not not (predicate (expression
>   (full_column_name (table_name (id (simple_id p))) . (id (simple_id
>   BusinessEntityID)))) (comparison_operator ! =) (expression
>   (full_column_name (table_name (id (simple_id adresstbl))) . (id
>   (simple_id BusinessEntityID)))))))))))))) (order_by_clause order by
>   (order_by_expression (expression (full_column_name (table_name (id
>   (simple_id p))) . (id (simple_id BusinessEntityID))))))))))) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expression` could be one of many things. If you look at the grammar, you will see

```
expression
    : DEFAULT                                                  #primitive_expression
    | NULL                                                     #primitive_expression
    | LOCAL_ID                                                 #primitive_expression
    | constant                                                 #primitive_expression
    | function_call                                            #function_call_expression
    | expression COLLATE id                                    #function_call_expression
    | case_expr                                                #case_expression
    | full_column_name                                         #column_ref_expression
    | '(' expression ')'                                       #bracket_expression
    | '(' subquery ')'                                         #subquery_expression
    | '~' expression                                           #unary_operator_expression

    | expression op=('*' | '/' | '%') expression               #binary_operator_expression
    | op=('+' | '-') expression                                #unary_operator_expression
    | expression op=('+' | '-' | '&' | '^' | '|') expression   #binary_operator_expression
    | expression comparison_operator expression                #binary_operator_expression
    ;
```

You need to figure out which of these things it is. In your case, it is a `column_ref_expression`, in which case you will need to cast it to `Column_ref_expressionContext` and then you will be able to access `full_column_name`.

There are various ways to figure out which it is, or you can just assume if you only want to support a limited subset of the grammar.

Comment: This is so obvious! I was trying to create a new object like GrammarSQLParser.Column_ref_expressionContext with the parameter of the context.select_statement().query_expression().query_specification().select_list().select_list_elem().expression() and the object was always null. 

Thanks a lot!